# Turn off reasoner from Sparql Query in GraphDb

Tags: sparql, graphdb

Is there any way that I can turn off the reasoner while querying in GraphDb. There is >> symbol in Graphdb Sparql textbox to turn off the reasoner. I would like to know if we can turn off the reasoner from Sparql query itself. If so, is it recommended because some queries are easier to implement without the reasoner?

Comment: You can query the `explicit` context with `SELECT ... FROM <http://www.ontotext.com/explicit> ...`

Comment: Thanks AKSW. This is probably the most convenient and reliable option. I am assuming that the query performance will not be sacrificed or differ much as I am directly hitting the explicit graph of the database.

Answer (score 1):

All reasoning in GraphDB, except the `owl:sameAs` node expansion, is materialised when the statements are added/removed to the databases. According to the [GraphDB's documentation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/reasoning.html) you can turn off the reasoner with:

```
PREFIX sys: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/system#>
INSERT DATA {
  _:b sys:addRuleset "empty" .
  _:b sys:defaultRuleset "empty" .
}
```

After executing this operation the engine will no longer materialise any implicit triples in the database.

The other alternative also used by the SPARQL query view is to filter query-time the implicit statements with the special graph `onto:implicit`:

```
PREFIX onto: <http://www.ontotext.com/>
SELECT *
FROM onto:implicit 
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o 
}
```

or add the infer=false HTTP parameter to the SPARQL endpoint:

`curl -G  --data-urlencode query='select * where { ?s ?p ?o. }' 'http://localhost:7200/repositories/test' --data-urlencode infer=false`

Comment: Your first option would just avoid the inference of new triples, right? that means all previously materialized triples are still in the database. Regarding `FROM onto:implicit ` that would mean to get only inferred triples, exactly what he not wants, it should be the `explicit` context